# Hiding products behind a form

Tags: seo, indexing, e-commerce, web-crawler

I’m building a webshop that sells tires. I think it would be best user-friendly-wise to hide my products behind a search form, where you can select tire dimension, price range etc.

I’ve been told that Google will never submit a form, when crawling a site, so if I “hide” the products by using a form, does Google ever index my products?

If no, how do I best work around this? I’ve been thinking about doing a regular menu with category submenus (By brand, price range, speed limit etc.), so that Google can crawl my links and then replace the menu with a form using javascript. Then Google will crawl the links and the user will browse by form. But if I have 3000 products, could it cause duplicate content, flag for link spam (if there is such a thing) etc. ?

Comment: Do both. Make a form for users and pages with products for Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only way to find your products is to complete and submit a form then, no, Google nor any other search engine will be able to find and index that content. To get around this you have a few options:

1. Have an HTML sitemap on your site that also links to your products. Besides being a good way to generate internal links with good anchor text, it also allows search engines an alternative means to find that content.
2. Submit an XML sitemap. This is similar to an HTML sitemap except it is in XML and not publicly visible.
3. Use progressive enhancement and have a menu available to users who don't have JavaScript turned on. Then using JavaScript recreate your form functionality (assuming this increases usability).

You shouldn't run into any duplicate content issues unless you can get to same product using more then one URL. None of the above should cause that to happen. But if how you implemented your products can cause this to happen just use canonical URLs to identify the main URL. Then if the search engines see multiple pages for the same content they know which one is the main page and to include it in their search results.

Comment: The third option was actually what i had in mind, so thats what im going to to :) im going to use a xml sitemap too, but i would be huge if i had 3000 products in it? Should i just put all non-product site in the xml map, and then let google index the products by crawling through all the site links?

Comment: 3000 products is not considered a lot by website standards so putting them in a XML sitemap won't be an issue. In fact, you can put 50000 pages in an XML sitemap before you reach the maximum allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any on-site duplicate content issues, you can use the [canonical tag](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394) to indicate the primary content page. This works quite well for ecommerce sites where there are often multiple ways to reach a product listing.

Another way having a separate page for each product is helpful for SEO is that this can be used to create a good link for your visitors to share via social networking, forums, blogs and so forth. So, instead of sharing something like mytirestore.com?q=24892489892489248&p=824824 they can share something like mytirestore.com/firestone/r78-13. This kind of keyword targeted external link will also work wonders for you SEO for product specific keywords.